# MapBox - Fading in and out MGLPolygons

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Application built using the latest MapBox SDK on iOS. In the app we have a circle shown with specific radius when annotations are clicked on the map. To be able to show a circular overlay around the annotation, we use a helper function that creates a MGLPolygon that we add to the map.

As far as we know, this is the only method available to add a circle with a constant radius that follows the map scale when it is zoomed and panned.

```
//   First remove previous circle annotation
[self.mapboxView removeAnnotation:circleOverlay];

// Add a new circle annotation (MGLPolygon)
circleOverlay = [self polygonCircleForCoordinate:centerCoord withMeterRadius:selectedAnnotation.radius];
[self.mapboxView addAnnotation:circleOverlay];
```

This works as it should, but is visually not very appealing. When selecting a new symbol on the map we need to first remove the previous circleOverlay and then add the new one. There is a lot of flickering when doing this and we would like to add and remove the MGLPolygons with fade in/out animations to make the experience smoother.

Can anyone think of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with MapBox, but I'm pretty sure you can create a custom annotation view, then just add the fade in/out to the viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear function.

Comment: Yes, but the circle overlay should have a contant radius, so when you zoom the map in and out - the size of the circle is constant in relation to the map zoom level.  The MGLPolygon class is not inherited from UIView, so I am not able to set an alpha value on it like a regular AnnotaionView.